# reducer not fired upon calling dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I am new to redux and I'm having trouble with setting it up.

I am trying to dispatch an action whenever I click the login button. but the reducer does not get called. Using Thunk, I can see that my action DOES get dispatched. My terminal prints previous state, current action, and next state whenever I click the login button and I've successfully used console.log in LoginAction.js.

That said, the emitted action does not seem to call my reducer to act. I tried console.log in my reducer, and it doesn't print anything. The current action displayed by Thunk is also displayed as empty and my initialState does not change

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from './LoginAction';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        login: () => {dispatch(login())},
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        userInfo: state.userInfo
    }
};

const Login = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    class Login extends Component {
        onLogin() {
            this.props.login();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableHighlight 
                        onPress={() => this.onLogin()}>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
)
```

**LoginAction.js**

```
import { URL } from '../../core/api';
import { fetchPost } from '../../core/util';

export const LOGIN_REQUESTED = "LOGIN_REQUESTED";
loginRequested = () => {
    console.log("in request");
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUESTED,
    };
}


export const LOGIN_RECEIVED = "LOGIN_RECEIVED";
loginReceived = (loginAttemptResult) => {
    console.log("in receive");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(loginAttemptResult));
    return {
        type: LOGIN_RECEIVED,
        loginAttemptResult
    };
}

export function login() {
    let loginApi = URL + "/login";
    console.warn(loginApi)

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loginRequested());
        const formData = {
            email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
            id: '000000000000'
        }
        fetchPost(loginApi, formData)
            .then(loginAttemptResult => {
                console.log(loginAttemptResult);
                dispatch(loginReceived(loginAttemptResult));
            })
            .catch(console.log("fail :("));
    };
}
```

In LoginAction.js, my console.log prints "in request", "in receive", and "fail :(". However, I've made sure that the HttpRequest/Fetch is successful by printing the content of the payload

**LoginReducer.js**

```
import {LOGIN_REQUESTED, LOGIN_RECEIVED} from "./LoginAction";
import {RESPONSE_STATUS} from "../../constants";
import {userInfoState} from "../../core/initialState";

export default function loginReducer(state = userInfoState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUESTED:{
            console.log("reducer 1");
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoggingIn: true
            });
        }
        case LOGIN_RECEIVED: {
            console.log("reducer 2");
            const {status, message} = action.loginAttemptResult;
            const errorMsg = (status === RESPONSE_STATUS.ERROR) && message;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoggingIn: false, errorMsg,
            });
        }
        default:
             console.log("default reducer");
             return state;
    }
}
```

Nothing in LoginReducer.js got printed in my console

**store.js**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { REHYDRATE, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import createActionBuffer from 'redux-action-buffer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2'

import loginReducer from '../screens/Login/LoginReducer';

let storage = AsyncStorage;

const config = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
}

export default function configureStore() {

    let reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, {
        userInfo: loginReducer,
    });

    const middleware = [thunk];
    middleware.push(createLogger());

    middleware.push(createActionBuffer(REHYDRATE));
    const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        undefined,
        compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
    );

    persistStore(
        store,
        null,
    );
    return store;
}
```

My suspicion is that I've got something wrong in my store.js, but I can't figure it out.

This is my first question on the site and English is not my native language. If something is unclear and needed clarification, please ask

Edit: This is the log from thunk

```
Login button clicked
in request
action LOGIN_REQUESTED 
prev state Object {
    "userInfo": Object {...},
}
action Object {
    "type": "LOGIN_REQUESTED",
}
next state Object {
    "userInfo": Object {...},
}
fail :(
Object {
    "data": Array [
            Object {
                ...
            },
        ],
    "message": "success",
    "status": 1,
}
in receive
action Object {
    "loginAttemptResult": Object {
        "data": Array [
            Object {...},
        ],
        "message": "success",
        "status": 1,
    },
    "type": "LOGIN_RECEIVED",
}
next state Object {
    "userInfo": Object {
    ...
    },
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but in your reducer switch your types are written as variables, not strings. The reducer is listening for an action with type 'LOGIN_REQUESTED' but instead you're passing it the action directly.

Reducers listen for dispatched actions. There's no need to import the action in the reducer.

Comment: It was the formatting of my previous company. I tried changing the variables to strings as you suggested, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: In your store your createStore function adds preloaded state as undefined. I'm not sure if this would break anything, but the docs require "must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand." If you don't have a preloaded state it should be safe to leave it out.

Comment: If you add a console.log to your switch's default case, does that show anything?

Comment: You should go step by step. After properly defining your functions, be sure to see loginAttemptResult. After this put a console.log in your reducer as @FranCarstens. But I prefer the top line, not a particular case.

Comment: I tried and no, that doesn't show anything. I'm editing the question to include what you said

Comment: I've edited the question to include what my terminal prints

Comment: To clarify, I've put the console.log in the reducer at top line as you said. It doesn't get printed

Comment: Are you 100 that your actions are being dispatched? What does your action log look like in console?

Comment: I don't use `logger` middleware but I see a `fail :(` there. So, I think your actions are not being dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

I can't examine all the codes (such as a complex store for me) but the only mistake I can see here is you are not properly defining `loginRequested` and `loginReceived` functions in your action creators file.

```
const loginRequested ...
const loginReceived ...
```

So, maybe they are not triggered at all and your action does not hit the reducers.

Comment: This may be the problem. Wouldn't you expect to see an undefined error in the console though?

Comment: Actually yes we should see in the console. This is why I'm not quite sure and said "maybe" :)

Comment: Also, OP says there are logs about dispatches, so probably this is not the right answer for the problem.

Comment: I tried defining those function as constants as you said, and it doesn't change anything. The console does not print any error either before or after I did so. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Ok then. I tried your code in a simpler way and it works with a simple store and a fake login request.

Comment: Can you post your code with the simple store somewhere?

Comment: I got rid of the persist library just like you wrote and it worked, thanks! My app requirements are forcing me to use persist though. Right now I'll be using the simpler store, but I need to learn how to configure redux-persist eventually...

Comment: Glad that you have found the problem eventually.